# Javascript library development scopes and namespaces

Tags: javascript, namespaces

we currently learn some Javascript stuff in a course at the university.
For that we implement a library for common tasks like show(), hide(), write and such things.

Currently im running with an implementation like:

```
var myLib_maker = function () {
/*
private scope
*/
var debuggingMode=true;
var currentElement=null;
/*
end private scope
*/
return {
    getElement: function (id) {
        var o;
        if (typeof id === 'string') { o = document.getElementById(id); }
        if (!!(o && o.nodeType !== 1)) { 
            throw {
                name: 'Type Error',
                message: 'Wrong node type at id: '+id
            } 
        }
      currentElement=o;
      return this;
    },
    getCurrentElement: function() {
        console.log(currentElement)
        return currentElement;
    },
    isVisible: function () {
        return this.getCurrentElement().style.display.toLowerCase() === "block"; 
    },
    show: function () {
        this.debug("show "+this.getCurrentElement())
        this.getCurrentElement().style.display = "block";
        return this;
    },
    hide: function () {
        this.debug("hide "+this.getCurrentElement())
        this.getCurrentElement().style.display = "none";
        return this;
    },
    toggle: function() {
        this.debug("toggle "+this.getCurrentElement())
        this.isVisible() ? this.hide(): this.show();
        return this;
    },
    write: function (content){
        this.debug("write to"+this.getCurrentElement().id);
        var tg = this.getCurrentElement().tagName.toLowerCase();
        if (tg === 'input' || tg === 'textarea') {
            currentElement.value = content; 
        } else { 
            currentElement.innerHTML = content;
        }
        return this
    },
    debug: function (what) {
        if (debuggingMode===true){
            console.log("[DEBUG] "+what);
        }
        return this;
    }

};
  }
  var myLib=myLib_maker();
```

Than I have an external function (for testing) to switch 2 textareas contents.

```
 function switchEditors(id1, id2){
      c1=myLib.getElement(id1).getCurrentElement().value;
      c2=myLib.getElement(id2).getCurrentElement().value;
      myLib.getElement(id1).write(c2)
      myLib.getElement(id2).write(c1)
 }
```

I first tried with the following code, which obviously does not work, cause I overwrite my private currentElement and so I write always to id2

```
function switchEditors(id1, id2){
      tmp=myLib.getElement(id1).getCurrentElement().value
      myLib.getElement(id1).write(myLib.getElement(id2).getCurrentElement().value)
      myLib.getElement(id2).write(tmp)
 }
```

But what I really wanted initially was not using a private currentElement variable.
The first implementation of the write method extended the Element Object

```
Element.prototype.write= function (content){
    var tg = this.tagName.toLowerCase();
    if (tg === 'input' || tg === 'textarea') {
        this.value = content; 
    } else { 
         this.innerHTML = content;
    }
    return this;
}
```

and such the getElement function returned

```
document.getElementById(id)
```

I want cascading (I hope this is the right word -> I mean the myLib.getElement("myid").show().hide() concatenation thing) and getting direct access to 
all Element attributes but we must not use global scope for our library, so I have to encapsulate my library in any way.

So is there an elegant way to use the cascading thing and be able to get a direct access to all attributes on an element object without implementing each method within the global element scope?

Or is my lib desing completely wrong and has to be done totally different.
If so, just tell me, I appreciate any help.
(I tried to figure out how jQuery actually implement these things, but didn't get a real clue how it is done ... too much code ... :) )

I hope I described my wishes and requirements. If not please ask for more specific details.

Comment: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/library-foundation-code/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've figured out, the `currentElement` is shared between calls to `getElement`. Instead you could create a new instance of myLib-object with [Object.create](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) and bind `currentElement` to that.

```
getElement: function (id) {
    var o, self = Object.create(this);
    /* ... */
    self.currentElement = o;
    return self;
}
```

And use `this.currentElement` throughout so that each call uses its own current element.

Comment: this works as expected. thank you. Maybe there are solutions which are more beautiful than singletons, but what to say, this is exactly what I need.

Comment: It's not a singleton. You've created an object that you are creating copies of using prototypical inheritance. It's definately the way to go over `new`.

Comment: myLib_maker as originally created is indeed a singleton, even if you are overriding it internally and even though JS offers the ability to utilize any object (including singletons) for inheritance. Yes, you are creating an object which inherits from the current object, but in this case the inheritance is needless. By using `Object.create`, you are building an extra function into memory where a simple `this` (without a new function) would suffice. My example helps avoid the need for `new` while offering the benefit of not creating and invoking functions every time you call getElement.

Answer (score 1):

While Magnar's solution will work with this (singleton) pattern, it is a better idea to avoid creating a whole new object each time you call `getElement`. There is a reason for creating "classes" instead of singletons.

You can do it like this:

```
var MyLib_Maker = (function () { // I capitalized the class as a helpful 
                                // convention recommended by Douglas Crockford

    // Private static vars
    var debuggingMode = true;
    var currentElement = null;

    // Private static methods
    function _myMethod (x, y) { // call below by _myMethod(3,4);
        return x * y;
    }

    // Private instance methods (but only if called properly: 
    // invoke below by _instMethod.call(this, 3, 4); )
    function _instMethod (x, y) {
        return this.anInstanceNumber * x * y;
    }

    // Private instance properties (quite cumbersome but doable if you 
    // absolutely must--e.g., for classes whose objects need to be clean when iterated)
    // See http://brettz9.blogspot.com/2009/02/true-private-instance-variables-in.html
    // and http://brettz9.blogspot.com/2009/02/further-relator-enhancements.html
    // (put the Relator inside the closure if you don't want it reusable (and public),
    // but then your extending classes must be inside the closure too)

    function MyLib_Maker (arg1, arg2) {
        // I recommend the following check to allow your class to be
        // instantiated without the 'new' keyword (as in jQuery/$):
        if (!(this instanceof MyLib_Maker)) {
            return new MyLib_Maker(arg1, arg2);
        }
        // Other constructor code here
        // ...
    }
    // Methods added on the prototype benefit from merely 
    // providing a low-memory reference across all instances; 
    // this will avoid adding a whole new object unnecessarily 
    // into memory
    MyLib_Maker.prototype.getElement = function () {
        // ....
        return this; // Keep the chain going (if not public
        // properties, you could add a method which also avoids 
        // extending the chain, like $(el).get() in jQuery
    };


    return MyLib_Maker;
}()); // We can invoke immediately to wrap up the closure

// Usage example:
var mlm = MyLib_Maker(2, 3).getElement().doSomething();
```

By the way, what you describe is called chaining; cascading is used in the likes of CSS to indicate that like different waves out of a waterfall, one may write over the other, as you can do by writing rules which override prior ones in CSS.

And it is good you moved away from overriding the Element object because, whatever the browser incompatibilities, this is the worst kind of global namespace pollution because it affects all elements, increasing the chance that another library which depends on that method (or which is careless in overriding the built-in prototypes itself) may get you unexpected results.

Comment: Hi, thank you. What I'm not really getting is, why do you call the constructor with two additional arguments. If I understand it correctly, I only need the arguments if I want to use them in the private namespace. Is this correct? Would this also work if I just leave them out or are they used to identify the object itself to decide var mlm = MyLib_Maker(2, 3) is another object than var mlm2 = MyLib_Maker(2, 4). Because I dont want to create a seperate instance by hand each time. Later usage should only be mlm.dowhatIlike().oreventhis()

Comment: @evildead: How are you implementing? Want to put it at jsfiddle.net? As far as constructor arguments, you only need them if you want the constructor to have args. The inside constructor is like any constructor made outside of a closure with the exception that it has access to all the private variables or methods. You can use it to initialize your object if you like (e.g., to set private or public properties), but it's not necessary. My using arguments was just to show how to pass multiple arguments (i.e., spell them out when forcing a call without `new` to be treated as though it does have).

Comment: @evildead: To continue, no, the arguments do not identify the object. This is just a regular constructor. Yes, it can be chained as you request. Just try making a version and show us on jsfiddle if you're still having trouble.

Comment: Douglas Crockford recommends using capital letters only for contructors to be used with `new`

Comment: JavaScript does not have classes. Prototypical inheritance is how JavaScript works, so I think this answer isn't very helpful at all.

Comment: @Magnar: Firstly, we do use `new` internally, and secondly, I don't worship Crockford; I was only incidentally mentioning him as he popularized the convention; the reason I cite it is because it makes sense to have a convention to distinguish constructor functions from utility functions. And yes, I'm quite aware JavaScript uses prototypal inheritance, as my example should show, since the class I built uses the prototype and allows for extensibility.

Comment: @evildead: If you look at jsfiddle, I have adapted your code and it is working now (though be sure to use "no wrap (head)" as this defines globals needed by your HTML, and I didn't want to avoid using 'var'). The code basically just needed to define currentElement as an instance property: `this.currentElement`. I also got rid of all the surrounding code, as the purpose of my example above was just to get you started. Hope that works for you.

Comment: @brett: does not work if last line of switchEditors is commented out. The way it is working with the last line was already possible with my code posted yesterday. http://jsfiddle.net/APnpH/18/

Comment: @evildead: I'm not clear what you're saying. I updated the switchEditors code a little, btw, to try to make it a little clearer. If there is a problem with sharing the same `currentElement`, you can invoke `MyLib_Maker` another time.